# "split" dataframe per month based on columns Start/End

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to "split" a 15 million line df of the following form:

```
library(lubridate)
dateStart <- c(lubridate::ymd("2010-01-01"))
dateEnd <- c(lubridate::ymd("2010-03-06"))
length <- c(65)
Amt <- c(348.80)

df1 <- data.frame(dateStart, dateEnd, length, Amt)

df1
#    dateStart    dateEnd length   Amt
# 1 2010-01-01 2010-03-06     65 348.8
```

into something like:

```
dateStart    dateEnd length   Amt
1 2010-01-01 2010-01-31     31 166.35
2 2010-02-01 2010-02-28     28 150.55
3 2010-03-01 2010-03-06     6 32.19
```

Where length is the number of days and Amt is the pro-rata amount for the number of days. Does anybody know how to do this? Someone mentioned the `padr` package to me but I do not know how to use it for this specific purpose.

Thank you in advance

Comment: How do you define lengths 30 and amount 160.98? Why 30 days(?) in a month?

Comment: i corrected the lengths in the example to show the real number of days. Amount is pro-rata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume you have an some sort of unique id field in your data set so you have a unique record. Otherwise this is not going to work. I also added 1 extra record so we can see everything works on multiple records.

Data:

```
library(lubridate)
id <- c(1:2) # added id field needed for unique record and needed for grouping
dateStart <- c(lubridate::ymd("2010-01-01", "2011-01-09"))
dateEnd <- c(lubridate::ymd("2010-03-06", "2011-04-09"))
length <- c(65, 91)
Amt <- c(348.80, 468.70)

df1 <- data.frame(id , dateStart, dateEnd, length, Amt)
```

First create a data.frame which has the id and missing months. We need `dplyr`, `tidyr` and `padr`. Create groups per unique id, `gather` the dates so we have start and end date in 1 column. For `padr` to extend months we first need to `thicken` the data.frame. Get rid of not needed columns and fill in the missing months.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(padr)

#create last_day function for later use
last_day <- function(date) {
  ceiling_date(date, "month") - days(1)
}

dates <- df1 %>% 
  select(id, dateStart, dateEnd) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  gather(names, dates, -id) %>% 
  arrange(id, dates) %>% 
  thicken(interval = "month") %>% # need to thicken first for month interval
  select(-c(names, dates)) %>% 
  pad(interval = "month")

dates
# A tibble: 7 x 2
# Groups:   id [2]
     id dates_month
  <int> <date>     
1     1 2010-01-01 
2     1 2010-02-01 
3     1 2010-03-01 
4     2 2011-01-01 
5     2 2011-02-01 
6     2 2011-03-01 
7     2 2011-04-01
```

Next join back the data to the original data.frame

```
df_extended <- inner_join(dates, df1, by = "id") 

df_extended
# A tibble: 7 x 6
# Groups:   id [2]
     id dates_month dateStart  dateEnd    length   Amt
  <int> <date>      <date>     <date>      <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 2010-01-01  2010-01-01 2010-03-06     65  349.
2     1 2010-02-01  2010-01-01 2010-03-06     65  349.
3     1 2010-03-01  2010-01-01 2010-03-06     65  349.
4     2 2011-01-01  2011-01-09 2011-04-09     91  469.
5     2 2011-02-01  2011-01-09 2011-04-09     91  469.
6     2 2011-03-01  2011-01-09 2011-04-09     91  469.
7     2 2011-04-01  2011-01-09 2011-04-09     91  469.
```

Now to get to the end result. need to use `case_when`, `ifelse` doesn't return the data in date format for some reason. The `case_when` replace set the correct start and end dates (I assume you need the exact start date, not the first of the month, otherwise adjust code to use dates_month instead.) I create an amount per day (amt_pd) variable to be able to multiply this with the number of days in the month to get the pro-rata amount for the number of days in the month.

```
df_end <- df_extended %>% 
  mutate(dateEnd = case_when(last_day(dates_month) <= dateEnd ~ last_day(dates_month),
                             TRUE ~ dateEnd),
         dateStart  = case_when(dates_month <= dateStart ~ dateStart,
                                TRUE ~ dates_month),
         amt_pd = Amt / length, 
         length = dateEnd - dateStart + 1,
         Amt = amt_pd * length) %>% 
  select(-c(dates_month, amt_pd)) # get rid of not needed columns

df_end
# A tibble: 7 x 5
# Groups:   id [2]
     id dateStart  dateEnd    length Amt             
  <int> <date>     <date>     <time> <time>          
1     1 2010-01-01 2010-01-31 31     166.350769230769
2     1 2010-02-01 2010-02-28 28     150.252307692308
3     1 2010-03-01 2010-03-06 6      32.1969230769231
4     2 2011-01-09 2011-01-31 23     118.462637362637
5     2 2011-02-01 2011-02-28 28     144.215384615385
6     2 2011-03-01 2011-03-31 31     159.667032967033
7     2 2011-04-01 2011-04-09 9      46.354945054945
```

All of this could be done in one go. But if you have 15 million rows it might be better to see if the intermediate steps work. Also note that `pad` has a `break_above` option.

> This is a numeric value that indicates the number of rows in millions
>   above which the function will break. Safety net for situations where
>   the interval is different than expected and padding yields a very
>   large dataframe, possibly overflowing memory.